# Why "ходила" and not "ездила"?

Tags: грамматика

In the phrase:
 - "Где ты была?"
 - "Я ходила на почту "

Why `ходила` is used instead of `ездила`?

Comment: because it is assumed that the post office is not that far away and most probalby in a working distance. Please, put some effort in at least formatting you question.

Comment: thank you for the help, but how the question is supposed to be formated? i usually do different, but because anothers reclamations i did what i did here.

Comment: What did you expect instead of "была"?

Comment: Some word that i may not know, is just because i usually think была meaning `to be` rather than to stay, but after you asked i just realized that may the adverb of location requires the была, is it far from right?

Comment: Within a city, places like restaurants, the post office, the theatre are like events. You go there and spend some time. Ходить in these cases = быть and just says that you went there spend some time then left. And ходить is used because there for the same reason we don't say "I drove to the restaurant, or the theatre, but instead say "I went there". Within cities, unless you really want to emphasize transport, the verb ходить/идти will be used.

Comment: I think if a person really visited a post office using some sort of transport - they will use "Ездила на почту" instead - there is absolutely no problem with using "ездила" in this case.

Comment: there isn't but grammars often remark that within cities people use ходить/идти—even when busses are involved. But I mean both are valid of course.

Comment: We can use "ходила" meaning "была" more generally, even if means of transport were used. But other verbs like ездила, бегала, моталась  are also used.

Comment: Because she has no car!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We sometimes use the verb **ходить** in a broad sense of **быть**.Consider it not like a movement (on foot),unless the post office is not very far, but more like an event. We say **ходила** even if we used means of transport. We also use other words in the same sense (бегать,slang *мотаться*,*слетать*), all of them meaning **to quickly go and come back**.

> Где ты была?– Да на почту ходила/бегала/моталась/слетала.

It doesn't mean you actually **ran** or **flew** somewhere, you just visited the place. But it is also correct to use *ездила*, if you want to mention the means of transport.